# How to make chromosome color maps for bed ranges

Tags: r, gviz

I have genomic .bed file data of 4 different types; type A,B,C,D. These are some examples-

Type A:

```
1   101380000   101710000   A
1   110085000   110320000   A
```

Type B:

```
1   100930000   101335000   B
1   10430000    10560000    B
```

Type C:

```
1   101775000   101825000   C
1   103570000   104070000   C
```

Type D:

```
1   153325000   153475000   D
1   156355000   156415000   D
```

This data is for chr1, but I such data for all the chromosomes. I want to draw a chromosome map (possibly using the Gviz package?) which can assign different colors to the 4 types of genomic ranges and make me an idiogram like plot for the chromosomes I wish to see, so I know where my ranges physically are, on the chromosome.

Can this be done using the **Gviz** package in R? If not, what is the best way and code to do this?

Comment: On my (retina) screen some of these ranges would be less than a pixel in width. Are you sure this is the best approach?

Comment: @heathobrien Aah then I guess perhaps not :/ Can you show me how to do it anyway, then I can think about it. My bed files are ~1000-4000 lines in number so maybe I can see something.

Comment: @heathobrien on smaller chromosomes perhaps

Comment: I haven't done that specifically, but it should be easy with ggbio. If you want to see the distribution of your ranges across a chromosome, I suggest plotting the centres of the ranges as points. There are a bunch of examples [here](http://www.tengfei.name/ggbio/docs/man/layout_karyogram-method.html)

Comment: You could also use karyoploteR too instead of Gviz, see the vignette in Bioconductor to see the resulting plots

Comment: Take a look at Circos highlights, zoomed into a subregion of chr1, e.g. http://circos.ca/documentation/tutorials/highlights/wedges/images

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [karyoploteR](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/karyoploteR.html) to plot your regions on an ideogram quite easily.

**Disclosure:** I'm one of the authors of the tool.

For this example I'll start creating 4 GRanges with random regions, but with your data you should load your bed into R and split it into four GRanges.

```
library(karyoploteR)


typeA <- createRandomRegions(nregions = 100, length.mean = 5e6, length.sd = 3e6)
typeB <- createRandomRegions(nregions = 20, length.mean = 15e6, length.sd = 10e6)
typeC <- createRandomRegions(nregions = 1000, length.mean = 5e5, length.sd = 2e5)
typeD <- createRandomRegions(nregions = 100, length.mean = 2e6, length.sd = 5e6)

colors <- c(A="#FFD700", B="#00BFFF", C="#FF7F50", D="#90EE90")
```

And we can plot them. We have to start creating an empty ideogram with `plotKaryotype` (we are working with human here, but you can use [any genome you want](https://bernatgel.github.io/karyoploter_tutorial//Tutorial/CustomGenomes/CustomGenomes.html)) and then plot the regions in the GRanges with [`kpPlotRegions`](https://bernatgel.github.io/karyoploter_tutorial//Tutorial/PlotRegions/PlotRegions.html). As a bonus, if two regions overlap it will plot them one above the other.

```
kp <- plotKaryotype(genome = "hg19")

kpPlotRegions(kp, data=typeA, r0=0, r1=0.2, col=colors["A"])
kpPlotRegions(kp, data=typeB, r0=0.25, r1=0.45, col=colors["B"])
kpPlotRegions(kp, data=typeC, r0=0.5, r1=0.7, col=colors["C"])
kpPlotRegions(kp, data=typeD, r0=0.75, r1=0.95, col=colors["D"])
legend(x = "right", legend = names(colors), fill = colors, border=NA)
```

And you'll get something similar to this

[image]

In this example we have fairly large regions and not a lot of them. As @heathobrien pointed out, plotting the actual regions in the whole genome plot might not be the best visualization option. You can either use [`zoom`](https://bernatgel.github.io/karyoploter_tutorial//Tutorial/Zoom/Zoom.html) to create different plots of smaller parts of the genome or change your visualization to show the density of regions along the genome with [`kpPlotDensity`](https://bernatgel.github.io/karyoploter_tutorial//Tutorial/PlotDensity/PlotDensity.html).

Plotting the density and tweaking a bit the visualization (and changing the example to have 10 times more regions) with this codei

```
typeA <- createRandomRegions(nregions = 1000, length.mean = 5e6, length.sd = 3e6)
typeB <- createRandomRegions(nregions = 200, length.mean = 15e6, length.sd = 10e6)
typeC <- createRandomRegions(nregions = 10000, length.mean = 5e5, length.sd = 2e5)
typeD <- createRandomRegions(nregions = 1000, length.mean = 2e6, length.sd = 5e6)

kp <- plotKaryotype(genome = "hg19", plot.type = 4, 
                    ideogram.plotter = NULL, labels.plotter = NULL, main="Density")
kpAddCytobandsAsLine(kp)
kpAddChromosomeNames(kp, srt=45)

kpPlotDensity(kp, data=typeA, r0=0, r1=0.2, col=colors["A"], window.size     = 10e6)
kpAddLabels(kp, labels = "Type A", r0=0, r1=0.2)
kpPlotDensity(kp, data=typeB, r0=0.25, r1=0.45, col=colors["B"], window.size = 10e6)
kpAddLabels(kp, labels = "Type B", r0=0.25, r1=0.45)
kpPlotDensity(kp, data=typeC, r0=0.5, r1=0.7, col=colors["C"], window.size = 10e6)
kpAddLabels(kp, labels = "Type C", r0=0.5, r1=0.7)
kpPlotDensity(kp, data=typeD, r0=0.75, r1=0.95, col=colors["D"], window.size = 10e6)
kpAddLabels(kp, labels = "Type D", r0=0.75, r1=0.95)
```

it would look something like this

[image: Whole Genome Plot of density of regions using karyoploteR]

The plots could be tweaked a lot changing various parameters and you could add other data on top of it if needed. You can find more information on the Bioconductor landing page or at the [karyoploteR's Tutorial and Examples page](https://bernatgel.github.io/karyoploter_tutorial/).

Comment: @bernatgel thank you so much for the elaborate answer! I used karyoploteR as the comments suggested, but your code gave me a better answer, which I can now tweak about. Thanks!

Comment: I [moved the discussion to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73895/discussion-on-answer-by-bernatgel-how-to-make-chromosome-color-maps-for-bed-rang) so as not keep this excellent answer clean and not to bother bernatgel with the discussion.

Comment: The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpKhPald/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
package ‘karyoploteR’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3) 

Can you give me a solution for this? Do I upgrade my R?

Comment: @rishi karyoploteR is available from R3.4 onward, so it should be available for 3.4.3. Are you installing it with biocLite? 
    source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    biocLite("karyoploteR")

Comment: @bernatgel yes, that's exactly what I did. I even updated my biocLite to be sure

Comment: @rishi Can you send me the exact code you are using to install karyoploteR and the output of sessionInfo()? maybe by email would be best: bgel at igtp.cat   and I'll try to understand what's going on

Comment: @bernatgel This does not work for me